# Issues with predicting a projectile motion by Euler's method

Tags: numerical-methods, python, projectile-motion

I am trying to predict the projectile motion of a basketball. Please not that I am not considering any effect of air drag, just the effect of g.I am using euler's method for this purpose.

I am able to track the ball quite accurately. However the issue is with the prediction part. Here is the code of euler's method which I am using:

```
def euler(euler_center, euler_velocity):
euler_center[0] = euler_center[0] + euler_velocity[0] * timeStepSize *gTimesteps *0.707
euler_center[1] = euler_center[1]  + euler_velocity[1] * timeStepSize

euler_velocity[0] = euler_velocity[0]  * timeStepSize
euler_velocity[1] = euler_velocity[1] + gTimesteps * timeStepSize

return (euler_center, euler_velocity)
```

The euler_center calculated by it after 20 iterations is:

```
[[331.3899068333333, 162.3366666666667]
[331.39290372777776, 167.5727277777778]
[331.3930036242592, 172.80818333333335]
[331.3930069541419, 178.04303333333334]
[331.393007065138, 183.27727777777778]
[331.3930070688379, 188.51091666666667]
[331.39300706896125, 193.74395]
[331.39300706896535, 198.9763777777778]
[331.39300706896546, 204.20820000000003]
[331.39300706896546, 209.4394166666667]
[331.39300706896546, 214.6700277777778]
[331.39300706896546, 219.90003333333334]
```

And something like that.

However, the centers tracked by my tracking algorithm are:

```
(339, 167)
(332, 158)
(325, 151)
(319, 146)
(312, 140)
(306, 135)
(299, 130)
(293, 126)
(286, 122)
(280, 118)
(277, 117)
(269, 112)
(254, 111)
(248, 112)
```

Needless to say, thats pretty bad prediction. It seems that the first prediction is bit accurate.

By the way, this function is in a loop of 20 steps so the predicted value is again used to predict the next value. When the function is first called, `[331.3, 157.10000000000002]` is passed to it. timeStepSize is inverse of video FPS and

$$gTimesteps = -9.81 * 500(pixels Per Meter)$$

pixels per meter are just guessed.

So what is the issue here? Is this the wrong way to do prediction by euler's method? Or do I need to use some different method altogether? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the ball starting to float in the last measurements? Also your initial velocity can not be right, in x direction it should start with 6 pixel per time step. And what is the mysterious factor `gTimesteps*0.707` about?

Comment: gtimesteps is shown above. I used 0.707 to account for the projection angle. Actually I was playing around with it to see if it has any effect, but it was not the case.

Comment: Actually these are not the complete measurements. It starts as I have pasted there and continues with more or less same measurements. Also the initial velocity was found by subtracting the positions in first 2 frames. So it is pixels per frame.

Comment: A thought crossed my mind. Should I average out the velocities before the function has the chance to re-iterate ?

Comment: Maybe you should post a full script that reproduces the issue. Updating the velocity first leads to an algorithm called the symplectic Euler method. Also, maybe this is dumb but since you are not considering air resistance, can't you use [these equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_linear_acceleration_in_any_direction)?